# Trouble with execlp() and "cut" bash command: additional blank line added

Tags: c, process, pipe, exec

I have a C program where the father process creates two children processes: the first child needs to read from an existing text file, and using execlp("cut","cut", options...) it needs to extract the second word from each line in the text file and write it on a pipe.
The other process then needs to read each line (1 word per line) from the pipe and print something to stdout for every line.
The issue being, when reading from pipe I get an additional blank line at the end which messes up the lines count. I think the execlp created that additional line, because when I run the same command from the terminal, it seems to work fine.
Because of this the second child can't terminate and the program doesn't terminate normally. Why could this additional line be?

````
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <signal.h>

void wait_child() {
    int terminated, status;
    terminated=wait(&status);
    if (WIFEXITED(status)) {
        printf("Child termination ok\n");
    }else if (WIFSIGNALED(status)) {
        printf("Child termination not ok\n");
    }
}

void child1(int ppwrite, char* file) {
    int fd, nread;
    char buffer;
    char *f="-f2"; //i want the second word in each line
    char *d="-d " ""; 
    dup2(ppwrite,1); //output to pipe
    close(ppwrite);
    execlp("cut","cut", d,f,file,(char*)0); //Why does it write an additional blank line?
    perror("exec error\n");
}

void child2(int ppread) { //i want this to print: "Line X: word" for each line in pipe
    int nread,nlines;
    char buffer;
    nlines=0;
    printf("Line 1: ");
    while ((nread=read(ppread, &buffer, sizeof(buffer)))>0) {
        if (buffer=='\n') {
            nlines++;
             printf("\nLine %d: ", nlines+1);
        } else {
         printf("%c", buffer);
        }
       // printf("%d", nlines); //here I notice that it reads an additional not wanted char
    }
    close(ppread);
}

void handler(int signum) {
    if (signum==SIGALRM) {
        printf("Timeout\n");
        exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    
    int pid1,pid2;
    int pp[2];
    
    if (pipe(pp)<0) {
        printf("Errore creazione pipe\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    
    signal(SIGALRM, handler);
    alarm(5);
    
    pid1=fork();
    if (pid1<0) {
        printf("P1 could not be created\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    } else if (pid1==0) {
        close(pp[0]);
        child1(pp[1], "myfile.txt");
    } else {
        pid2=fork();
        if (pid2<0) {
            printf("P2 could not be created\n");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        } else if (pid2==0) {
            close(pp[1]);
            child2(pp[0]);
        } else {
            for (int i=0; i<2; i++) {
                wait_child();
            }
        }
        
    }
    
}```
````

Comment: Are you aware that for Unix `\n` is a line terminator, not a line separator, so text file should have a `\n` as last character of the last line?

Comment: It still gives me the same issue if I add \n as last character of the last line.

Comment: Let's be more explicit. You are printing `"\nLine %d"` as soon as you see a `\n`, thus included for the last `\n` of your input. My guess is that's what give you the impression of an additional empty line, but I've not run your code nor looked at it in depth.

Comment: It makes sense. But how would I go about printing it every time i read a \n, except the last time?

Comment: Change your POV: print `Line %d` before the first character of the line, not when reading a `\n` which should just set the flag indicating that the next character is the first character of line. Additional benefit, it would work correctly with empty files.

Comment: Now it seems to work. But the alarm goes off before it prints "Line 4: word". I don't get why.

Comment: I don't reproduce but I don't know what precisely you have done. A potentially related issue is that you should close pp[1]  before the second fork, not after and only in one of the branches.